# PySerial communication with variables

Tags: python, serial-port, arduino, pyserial

I am trying to interface with my Arduino via Pyserial on OS X. I am controlling LEDs with sending numbers from 0 to 9.
The code as in

```
import serial
arduino = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbserial', 9600)

arduino.write('5')
```

works perfectly fine, but I am trying to have the 5 in this example as a changeable variable but something like

```
arduino.write('%d') % 5
```

won't work. I don't know how to format a variable that the output is equal to the working example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were not formatting the string `%d` but the function call:

```
arduino.write('%d' % 5)
```

The `%` sign should go after the `'` immediately.

This will work, but it is also preferable to use tuples with format strings:

```
arduino.write('%d' % (5,))
```

Because when you have multiple parameters, you will anyway have to use it this way:

```
arduino.write('%d.%d' % (2, 3))
```

Answer (score 2):

The string formatting must go inside the parentheses of the function call.

e.g. `arduino.write("%d" % 5)`

Here's some information on [old-style string formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting)

Comment: I assume I am using "old-style formatting" here. What is the "new" way of formatting then?!

Comment: @birgit check out [the docs](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) for the 'new' string format syntax.